# How to update an activitys background when it's set to the systems wallpaper?

Tags: java, android, drawable, wallpaper

I have this code which allows me to set the current device wallpaper as my activitys background.

```
public void wallpaperBackground()
    {
        WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
        Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();

        View root = findViewById(R.id.home_view);
        root.setBackground(wallpaperDrawable);
    }
```

The problem is, if I change the wallpaper via settings it doesn't update on my app and I'm left with the previous wallpaper. How can I fix this?

Comment: Just call this `wallpaperBackground()` method in `onResume()` in your activity. See also [Managing the Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Comment: Thanks! why didn't I think of this. Doh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite easy actually:

Just call your `wallpaperBackground()` method in `onResume()` in your activity.

This will automatically apply the correct wallpaper when the activity resumes after the user comes back from another app.